# Possible to create an 'Updated!' icon similar to the 'New!' icon?

Tags: content-query-web-part, file-icons

The company intranet I am developing in Sharepoint 2010 has news articles that can remain featured on the front page for a long time, but is updated regularly.  Is it possible to set up an 'Updated!' icon similar to the existing 'New!' icon, but set up to appear next to any recently modified pages/documents for a set period of time?

I am already using a line of code in my XSL file to display the 'New!' icon on my Content Query Web Parts:

```
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:IfNew(string(@Created))"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif" alt="New" /></xsl:if>
```

I was hoping to use a similar technique to create a modified version using the Modified column instead of the Created column:

```
<xsl:if test="ddwrt:IfNew(string(@Modified))"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/1033/images/updated.gif" alt="Updated" /></xsl:if>
```

I found a link to a tutorial with similar code, but I've not been able to get it to work:

http://www.sharepoint-insight.com/2009/03/01/display-updated-today-indicator-just-like-new-icon-in-document-library/

I'll be very grateful if anyone knows a way to do this. :-)

Comment: you might be better off picking a solution, and come back and ask questions specific to your problems.

Comment: Thanks David, I have added some code I am already using to display the 'New!' icon, perhaps there is a variation that will work for an 'Updated!' icon.

Comment: I'm guessing the IfNew method is validating the date you're sending. Check out that method and see if the logic is correct.

Comment: As I understand it, the IfNew method simply checks a time/date column (such as the Created column) against a duration of time - I believe the default is 2 days.  

I read online that it should be possible to replace the Created column with any other time/date column.

Comment: Here's my source: http://sympmarc.com/2008/08/05/new-item-icon/#comments

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but knowing SP, sometimes things aren't always as straight forward. Silly question, is the updated.gif in that folder?

Comment: Haha, I know what you mean about overlooking the simple details, but the gif file is in the folder and I've viewed it on a direct link to make sure it displays ok.  SP often seems to give the impression of being straightforward when trying to do something - but then just isn't. :-/

Comment: I have to admit, I'm stunned that there isn't more support for this type of "Updated" icon requirement.  If Microsoft have already gone to the trouble of helping to clearly differentiate newly added content with a special icon, then why not clearly mark newly modified/updated content as well?